# Paired t-test...?

Tags: econometrics, descriptive-statistics, paired-comparisons, difference-in-difference

I want to analyze how the purchasing decision to buy a certified food product can be varied due to an information shock. My sample consists of 200 respondents and the responses were taken as dummies (1=purchasing, 0=not purchasing) in both situations (before and after information shock)

Can I use a paired t-test to analyze this?

Comment: With a t-test, paired or not, you assume that the response variable is normally distributed. With 0 or 1 as response, that is not the case. What you need is a comparison of paired proportions, which can be done with McNemar's test.